# How can I check the value of a Parameter is null in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I wanted to do a check and execute some transformation on XML. Below is the snippet I have used.

```
<xsl:param name="code" />

<xsl:if test="$code != ''">
<xsl:template match="partner/configuration/flags">
    <value><xsl:value-of select="$code"/></value>
</xsl:template>
  </xsl:if>
```

Trying condition check with '!=' is not giving expected the result. Can anybody help to sort out the mistake in this?

Comment: It is not valid to nest an `xsl:template` inside an `xsl:if`. To give a more detailed answer you might want to explain what problem you are trying to solve (i.e show your input XML and the output you expect. Thank you.

Comment: My requirement is like, I have to update <value> node, only if param code is not null.

Answer (score 1):

First, your code makes no sense, because you can't put `xsl:template` inside `xsl:if`.

Secondly, there's no such thing as "null" in the XSLT/XPath data model. You need to explain more clearly what you're trying to test for. An expression that returns an empty node-set? An element node that has no children? A node whose string-value is a zero-length string? This is a case where precision is essential.

Thirdly, if you're going to use "!=" you need to understand exactly what it means. If A is a node-set (or in 2.0, a sequence), then `A != ""` returns true if there is a node in A whose value is something other than the zero-length string. If A is an empty set, then the expression returns false. Most of the time, you probably want `not(A="")` rather than `A!=""` - they don't mean the same thing.